# Tags [print] vs [printing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

There are currently separate tags for [[print]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/print/info) and [[printing]](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/printing/info). Since they are both essentially the same thing, should 'print' tags be merged into 'printing' perhaps?

Is there any reason these two should be different?

The 'print' tag is currently used on slightly more questions, but from a purely grammatical view I thing 'printing' sounds a bit better. I could go either way though ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makes sense, [print](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print) is now mapped to [printing](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/printing)

```
updating post history, 25 rows affected
updating posts, 17 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 14 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [printing] and [print] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym print -> printing was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```